# Group action on co-induced module

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, group-actions, group-cohomology

$\newcommand\mb{\mathbb}\DeclareMathOperator{\Mor}{Mor}\DeclareMathOperator{\coInd}{coInd}$ Let $G$ be group, then we can define for an abelian group $N$ the co-induced module $\coInd^G(N) := \Mor_{\mb Z}(\mb Z[G], N)$ which is a $\mb Z[G]$-module.
How is the $G$-module structure on $\coInd^G(N)$ defined?
I can think of two ways, each one having its advantages.

1. for $h \in G$, $f \in \Mor_{\mb Z}(\mb Z[G],N)$ we define $(hf)(g) := f(gh)$.
2. for $h \in G, f \in \Mor_{\mb Z}(\mb Z[G],N)$ we define $(hf)(g) := f(h^{-1}g)$.

The first one has the advantage that if $M$ is a $G$-module, the unit map $\eta : M \to \DeclareMathOperator{\inclu}{Incl}\coInd^G(\inclu(M))$ which arises from the adjunction (here $\inclu : \mb Z[G]\text{-Mod} \to \operatorname{Ab}$ is the forgetful map)
$$ \Mor_{\mb Z}(\inclu(M),N)  = \Mor_{\mb Z[G]}(M,\coInd^G(N)) $$
which sends $\eta(m) := (g \mapsto gm)$ is a $\mb Z[G]$-module morphism:
$\eta(hm) : (g \mapsto ghm) = h (\eta(m))$.

On the other hand, the second definition has the advantage that if $G$ is a finite group,
the isomorphism between co-induction and induction (which is defined as $\DeclareMathOperator{\Ind}{Ind} \Ind^G(N) := N \otimes_{\mb Z} \mb Z[G]$)
$$ \begin{aligned}
\Mor_{\mb Z}(\mb Z[G],N) & \leftrightarrows N \otimes_{\mb Z}\mb Z[G] \\
\alpha : f & \mapsto \sum_{g \in G} f(g) \otimes g\\
1_g \cdot n & \leftarrow\!\shortmid n \otimes g\\
\text{with } 1_g(h) & := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } h = g,\\ 0 & \text{if } h\neq g
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}$$
is an isomorphism of $\mb Z[G]$-modules:
$$\alpha(hf) = \sum_{g \in G} (hf)(g) \otimes g
= \sum_{g \in G}f(h^{-1}g) \otimes g = \sum_{g \in G} f(g) \otimes hg = h \alpha(f).$$

Comment: nice .................+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one $(hf)(g) := f(gh)$ is the correct one, as we can write the isomorphism between co-induction and induction instead as

$$
\begin{aligned}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Mor}{Mor}\newcommand\mb{\mathbb}
\Mor_{\mb Z}(\mb Z[G],N) & \leftrightarrows N \otimes_{\mb Z}\mb Z[G] \\
\alpha : f & \mapsto \sum_{g \in G} f(g^{-1}) \otimes g\\
1_{g^{-1}} \cdot n & \leftarrow\!\shortmid n \otimes g\\
\text{with } 1_g(h) & := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } h = g,\\ 0 & \text{if } h\neq g
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
with the property that
$$
\alpha(hf) = \sum_{g \in G} (hf)(g) \otimes g
= \sum_{g \in G}f(g^{-1}h) \otimes g = \sum_{g \in G} f(g^{-1}) \otimes hg = h \alpha(f).
$$